# Http:pool возвращет класс ConnectException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php8

```
       Http::pool(fn(Pool $pool) => [
            $pool->email()->delete(sprintf('email/%d', $idemail),
                [
                    'key' => '***',
                ]
            ),
            $pool->phone()->delete(
                sprintf('phone/%d', $idphone),
                [
                    'key' => '***',
                ]
            ),
        ]);
```

Отрабатывает хорошо, но если сменится на некорректный url endpoint или ошибка сервера он возвращает ConnectExeption а не выбрасывает его в обработчки Laravel.
try catch не отлавливает его.
я могу проверять на instanceof, но хочется сделать красиво.
Как заствить его выбросить искючние, что бы я его отловил в Exception в фреймворке Laravel?

Comment: ну согласно документации сохраняете результат в переменную и делаете так: return `$responses[0]->ok() && $responses[1]->ok();`  если надо исключение выбрасывать, можно сделать так: `throw_if(!$responses[0]->ok() && !$responses[1]->ok(), \Exception::class, 'Сообщение')`

Comment: @DmitriiSedov Это хорошая мысль. Но ты создаешь Exception, а я хочу изначально выбрасить ConnectExeption, а не получать его.

Comment: я к тому что данный метод его автоматом не выбрасывает, согласно документации то же. Надо апи смотреть может там что есть. Но можно сделать обертку над методом, который будет это делать за вас. То есть создать фасад CustomPool к примеру и там вызывать `Http::pool` и внутрь передавать callback в результате вызова `CustomPool::pool($arrayRequests)` будет генерировать исключение где `Exception` спокойно заменяется на `ConnectExeption` (\Exception::class это для примера было приведено) и теперь CustomPool можно в try catch обернуть спокойно

Comment: @DmitriiSedov Спасибо,звучит не плохо,попробую.